# XMLHttpRequest status 0 error in Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm trying to make cross-domain cross-browser .js request (without any libs).

```
var isIE8 = window.XDomainRequest ? true : false;
var invocation = createCrossDomainRequest();
var url = 'http://someserver.com/cgi-bin/targets.cgi?sid=';

function createCrossDomainRequest(url, handler)
{
    var request;
    if (isIE8)
    {
        request = new window.XDomainRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return request;
}

function sendTarget(sid,target)
{
    if (invocation)
    {              
        var phone_id = getCookie('phone_cookie');
        url = url + sid +'&target='+target+'&phone_id='+phone_id+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
        if(isIE8)
        {
            invocation.onload = outputResult;
            invocation.open("GET", url, true);
            invocation.send();
        }
        else
        {
            invocation.open('GET', url, true);
            invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
            invocation.send();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var text = "No Invocation TookPlace At All";
    }
}

function handler(evtXHR)
{
    if (invocation.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (invocation.status == 200)
        {
            outputResult();
        }
        else
        {
            var text = "Invocation Errors Occured";
        }
    }
}

function outputResult()
{
    var response = invocation.responseText;
}
```

It works in IE, but not Mozilla and Chrome. These browsers are getting the error "Invocation Errors Occurred". invocation.status is zero. Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to *.

What I need to do to solve this problem?

I cant use any libraries, just clean JS (tech issues). No JQuery! This code need to be on many client web-sites (not one or two). I don't need to get an response, just need to send the request. And I'm not looped on XMLHttpRequest - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the code you supplied above and modified it slightly to be a bit more generic. However, you should be able to change it back to suit. The following code works in Chrome and Firefox:

```
var isIE8 = window.XDomainRequest ? true : false;
var url = 'http://www.phobos7.co.uk/research/xss/simple.php';
var resultText = '';
var invocation = createCrossDomainRequest();
makeRequest();

function createCrossDomainRequest(url, handler) {
    var request;
    if (isIE8) {
        request = new window.XDomainRequest();
    } else {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return request;
}

function makeRequest() {
    if (invocation) {
        if (isIE8) {
            invocation.onload = requestSucceeded;
            invocation.open("GET", url, true);
            invocation.send();
        } else {
            invocation.open('GET', url, true);
            invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
            invocation.send();
        }
    } else {
        resultText = "No Invocation TookPlace At All";
    }
}

function handler(evtXHR) {
    if (invocation.readyState == 4) {
        if (invocation.status == 200) {
            requestSucceeded();
        } else {
            resultText = "Invocation Errors Occured";
        }
    }
}

function requestSucceeded() {
    resultText = invocation.responseText;
    outputResult();
}

function outputResult() {
    document.getElementById( 'output' ).innerHTML = resultText;
}
```

You can test this here: http://jsfiddle.net/leggetter/3QfQe/

The response headers from this site - which allows the CORS - is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 12 Feb 2014 22:48:37 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.24
```

Only the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is required.

If you use the JavaScript above and you ensure that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header is set you will be able to make a cross domain request from JavaScript.

Comment: Code is working for the URL you have set. When I am trying any other cross domain URL in my application it is again giving status as 0. Please suggest.

Comment: "code is working" - did you mean to say it "is not working"? I've tested and it still works for me. Please provide more information if you are seeing a problem.

Comment: It is working with your url. When i am replacing it with my URL it is again giving status as 0 in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your code, having an issue with it though. In my browser I still get status = 0, but in fiddler I see a status 200 when I expect it. Both Chrome and IE. What can this be?

Comment: If the code isn't working it's important to know where is the page making the request hosted? where is the script handling the HTTP request hosted? What information does your browser developer tools tell you about the HTTP request. To determine why the exact same code is not working with in a different environment, and if checking the above doesn't help, it's likely best to create new new StackOverflow question which clearly states your environment setup. e.g.